# Passing Parameter to Crystal Report

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, parameter-passing, crystal-reports-2010

```
        Param1 = objDB.GetFieldValue(sSQL, 0)
        Param2 = objDB.GetFieldValue(sSQL, 1)
        Param3 = objDB.GetFieldValue(sSQL, 2)
        cSQL = ReportSQL
        .FillDataSet(cSQL, ReportDataSet)

        ds = .DSet

    End With

    crReportDocument.Load(RptPath & ReportFile)
    crReportDocument.SetDataSource(ds.Tables(0))
    crReportDocument.SetParameterValue("@Dibuat", Param1)
    crReportDocument.SetParameterValue("@Diperiksa", Param2)
    crReportDocument.SetParameterValue("@Disetujui", Param3)



    Me.FormBorderStyle = Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.Sizable

    CR.Visible = True
    CR.ReportSource = crReportDocument
    CR.RefreshReport()
    CR.DisplayGroupTree = False

    ds = Nothing
```

I want to pass parameters to Crystal Report but its always show pop to insert parameters, can you help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you possibly have more parameters that you've not passed in? Or parameters in a subreport that need populating?

Comment: This Solved, all because RefreshReport()